# Simple Looping code won't work

Tags: java

This is the simple code that I was practicing on since I'm totally new to Java. This is under the Day8 component of the kilobot tutorial available online here: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-8-looping

```
public class Looping {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean EarthIsSpinning = false;
    int counter = 9;

    while(counter >= 1){
        counter--;
        System.out.println(counter);
        if (counter == 4){
            EarthIsSpinning = true;
        }
        else{
            EarthIsSpinning = false;
        }

        while (EarthIsSpinning){
           System.out.println("The earth is still spinning");
        }
    }
}
```

And I edited the supposed tutorial that I was supposed to do. so I was wondering why the console keeps looping "The earth is still spinning" and not only that at 4 where EarthIsSpinning = True, since EarthIsSpinning is only true when counter is at 4.

Comment: one more `while` is needed?

Comment: You need `if(EarthIsSpinning)`. Not `while`.

Comment: Please look the EarthIsSpinning while is within the main while loop so inner while need to stop to move the next iteration of the outer while loop

Answer (score 3):

when counter = 4 it gets to this while loop

```
while (EarthIsSpinning){
        System.out.println("The earth is still spinning");
        }
```

and it never exits that loop back into your original while loop
the counter stays at 4 and EarthIsSpinning will stay true never exiting that while loop

Answer (score 1):

So `counter` is initially at 9.
Then you enter the outer while loop.

Inside, you decrement `counter` and check if it's 4. Since it's not, and `EarthIsSpinning` is set to `false` the inner while loop isn't executed and you go back to the beginning of the while loop.

This repeats until counter becomes 4 at which point `EarthIsSpinning` is set to true, and the inner while loop runs forever since its value is never changed.

Like Codebender commented, you probably want an if statement instead of a while.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Looping {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean EarthIsSpinning = false;
    int counter = 9;
    while(counter >= 1){
        counter--;
        System.out.println(counter);
    if (counter == 4){
            EarthIsSpinning = true;
            System.out.println("The earth is still spinning");
        }
    else{
        EarthIsSpinning = false;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Looping {
public static void main(String args[]) {
boolean EarthIsSpinning = false;
int counter = 9;



    while(counter >= 1)
    {
      counter--;
      System.out.println(counter);

      if (counter == 4)
      {
         EarthIsSpinning = true;
      }

      else
      {
         EarthIsSpinning = false;
      }

      if(EarthIsSpinning)
      {
         System.out.println("The earth is still spinning");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do that:

```
public class Looping {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int counter = 9;

        while(counter >= 1){
            counter--;
            if (counter == 4){
               System.out.println("The earth is still spinning");
            }else{
               System.out.println(counter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do make it correctly. Change the second while to if or keep the second while but change the flag earthIsSpinning to false.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        //flag to check the Spin
        boolean earthIsSpinning = false;
        //init the counter
        int counter = 9;

        //loop until counter is 0
        while(counter >= 1){
            counter--;
            System.out.println(counter);

            //condition to change flag to true
            if (counter == 4){
                earthIsSpinning = true;
            } else{
                earthIsSpinning = false;
            }
            //print the message if flag is true
            if (earthIsSpinning){
                System.out.println("The earth is still spinning: " + counter);
            }
        }
    }

Or you can do

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //flag to check the Spin
    boolean earthIsSpinning = false;
    //init the counter
    int counter = 9;

    //loop until counter is 0
    while(counter >= 1){
        counter--;
        System.out.println(counter);

        //condition to change flag to true
        if (counter == 4){
            earthIsSpinning = true;
        } else{
            earthIsSpinning = false;
        }
        //print the message if flag is true
        while (earthIsSpinning){
            System.out.println("The earth is still spinning: " + counter);
            earthIsSpinning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have logic error in your code

this loop condition always true and wont stop forever :

```
while (EarthIsSpinning){
           System.out.println("The earth is still spinning");
        }
```

its infinite loop , since when `counter == 4` , the bool variable `EarthIsSpinning = true;` so when you enter the second while loop the condition wont break.